# How to make one element appear after button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to work on a mini storytelling project that allows the story to unfold, essentially by clicking "Next" button on the page. I've used some JS code from CodePen and managed to make it work for the first paragraph, but not sure how to make it work for the following paragraphs.

The first bit of the code currently works fine. The issue is with displaying a second paragraph with the same typewriter effect, hiding the first paragraph, all by clicking the "Next" button. I would also want to add a "Restart" button at the end, that would allow it to go back to the intro page.

Here is the CodePen I have of it currently: https://codepen.io/annieelin/pen/eYOqbRG 
Below is a snippet of the HTML, please view the rest including CSS and JS on CodePen. (edit: added in JS as requested!)

```
<html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Bad+Script|Abril+Fatface|Indie+Flower&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet"><scriptsrc="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

<div class="intro">

<h1 class="title">
<span class="text-wrapper">
<span class="line line1"></span>
<span class="letters letters-left">The Flies</span>
<span class="letters ampersand">&amp;</span>
<span class="letters letters-right">The Honey</span>
<span class="line line2"></span>
</span>
</h1>

<div class="button">
<button class="start">Start</button>
</div>

</div>

<div class="part1">
<h2><div id="typedtext"></div></h2>
<button class="next">Next</button>
</div>

//header animation
anime.timeline({})
  .add({
  targets: '.title .line',
  opacity: [0.5,1],
  scaleX: [0, 1],
  easing: "easeInOutExpo",
  duration: 700
}).add({
  targets: '.title .line',
  duration: 600,
  easing: "easeOutExpo",
  translateY: (el, i) => (-0.625 + 0.625*2*i) + "em"
}).add({
  targets: '.title .ampersand',
  opacity: [0,1],
  scaleY: [0.5, 1],
  easing: "easeOutExpo",
  duration: 600,
  offset: '-=600'
}).add({
  targets: '.title .letters-left',
  opacity: [0,1],
  translateX: ["0.5em", 0],
  easing: "easeOutExpo",
  duration: 600,
  offset: '-=300'
}).add({
  targets: '.title .letters-right',
  opacity: [0,1],
  translateX: ["-0.5em", 0],
  easing: "easeOutExpo",
  duration: 600,
  offset: '-=600'
});

// set up text to print, each item in array is new line

var aText = new Array(
"A jar of honey was upset and the sticky sweetness flowed out on the 
table.","The sweet smell of the honey soon brought a large number of 
Flies buzzing around.", "They did not wait for an invitation. No, 
indeed; they settled right down, feet and all, to gorge themselves."
);

var iSpeed = 70; // time delay of print out
var iIndex = 0; // start printing array at this posision
var iArrLength = aText[0].length; // the length of the text array
var iScrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines

var iTextPos = 0; // initialise text position
var sContents = ''; // initialise contents variable
var iRow; // initialise current row

function typewriter()
{
sContents =  ' ';
iRow = Math.max(0, iIndex-iScrollAt);
var destination = document.getElementById("typedtext");

 while ( iRow < iIndex ) {
  sContents += aText[iRow++] + '<br />';
 }
 destination.innerHTML = sContents + aText[iIndex].substring(0, 
iTextPos) + "_";
if ( iTextPos++ == iArrLength ) {
iTextPos = 0;
iIndex++;
if ( iIndex != aText.length ) {
iArrLength = aText[iIndex].length;
setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
}
} else {
setTimeout("typewriter()", iSpeed);
}
}

typewriter();

//hide text on click, show story paragraph part 1 

$(".button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(".intro").hide();
  $("h2").show();
  $(".next").delay(1000*10).fadeIn(500);
  return false;
});
```

Here is the body text I'm using for the story: http://read.gov/aesop/127.html

Last question, the typewriting effect currently starts when the first page loads. I'm not sure how to get it to run only when the user clicks next. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Will you add the JS code to the snippet please?

Comment: Sure! I just added it to the code snippet.

Comment: `$('.next').on('click', function() {
    $('#typedtext').text(""); //Wipes the first paragraph
});` will clear the first paragraph on click of next